# Taylor's series problems

Tags: calculus, limits

Can you help please me solve this by using Taylor series?
I would be grateful if you can explain how did you solve it

$$\lim_{x\to 0}{\cosh{2x\over 2+x^4}+\cos{2x\over 2+x^4}-2e^{x^4\over 2}\over \tan\sqrt{1+x^4}-\tan\sqrt{1-x^4}}$$

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUZA1.png

Answer (score 0):

Let's develop every term to the fifth order:

$$\cosh \frac{2x}{2+x^4} \approx 1+ \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^4}{24} + \mathcal{O}(x^5)$$

$$\cos \frac{2x}{2 + x^4} \approx 1 - \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^4}{24} + \mathcal{O}(x^5)$$

$$2\ e^{x^4/2} \approx 2 + x^4 + \mathcal{O}(x^5)$$

$$\sqrt{1 + x^4} \approx 1 + \frac{x^4}{2} + \mathcal{O}(x^5)$$

$$\tan\sqrt{1+x^4} \approx \tan(1)  + \frac{1}{2}\left(1 + \tan(1)^2\right)x^4 + \mathcal{O}(x^5)$$

$$\sqrt{1 - x^4} \approx 1 - \frac{x^4}{2} + \mathcal{O}(x^5)$$

$$\tan\sqrt{1+x^4} \approx \tan(1)  +\left(- \frac{1}{2} - \frac{\tan(1)^2}{2}\right)x^4 + \mathcal{O}(x^5)$$

Accodino to that, we rewrite the function as

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1+ \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^4}{24} + 1 - \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^4}{24} - 2 - x^4}{\tan(1)  + \frac{1}{2}\left(1 + \tan(1)^2\right)x^4 -\tan(1)  -\left(- \frac{1}{2} - \frac{\tan(1)^2}{2}\right)x^4 }$$

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{-\frac{22}{24}}{\frac{2 + 2\tan(1)^2}{2}}$$

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{-\frac{11}{12}}{\tan(1)^2 + 1}$$

Now, generally speaking

$$\tan^2(x) + 1 = \frac{\sin^2(x)}{\cos^2(x)} + 1 = \frac{\sin^2(x) + \cos^2(x)}{\cos^2(x)} = \frac{1}{\cos^2(x)}$$

In your case

$$1 + \tan^2(1) = \frac{1}{\cos^2(1)}$$

hence the final result is

$$\boxed{-\frac{11}{12}\cos^2(1)}$$

Comment: P.s. For what concerns the Taylor series, they are easy. Just substitute $X$, the argument, with the function they are. Or go with baby steps, but try to get them, It's a good exercise.

Comment: Thank you very much,that was very helpful!!

Comment: @Nick you're  welcome ^^

Comment: @Nick Don't forget to up vote, for fairness ^_^

Comment: I did vote of course,but it says that i have to have more than 15 rep to raise the score publicly.

Comment: @Nick Ohh haha don't worry don't worry! :D The important thins is that you got some help ^^